# How to get default content type of list programmatically

Tags: 2010, content-type

How can I get default content type of sharepoint list programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SPContentType defaultCT = list.ContentTypes[0];`

This should get you the first content type which is the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following to determine the content type ordering (first is default).

```
SPList list = (code to identify your list instance here);
var listFolder = list.RootFolder;
var contentTypeOrder listFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder;
var defaultContentType = contentTypeOrder[0];
```

The defaultContentType variable will then contain the default content type object.